# Deskjet F4200 Vista compatibility

Tags: windows-vista, printer, compatibility

I have just bought an HP all in one deskjet F4200. There is no indication that it is suitable for Vista x32 in the manual. I´m a novice and don´t want to unpack the whole thing before taking it back if it is not suitable. Will it work with Vista Home Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are drivers [**here**](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3571309&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3390945&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2094) for the F4200 on Vista Home Basic so we can say it's compatible.

Comment: Just to update and inform. I installed the device using the information from the link Snark supplied. It works perfectly, so thanks again Snark.